# Best practice for custom subscribe action in Facebook app?

Tags: php, facebook, subscribe

I want to implement a facebook app, where I have several authors, which can post updates (text + image - similar to a very simple blog). Actual facebook users can browse the authors inside the app and read their entries.

I now want to create the possibility for facebook users to subscribe to one (or several) authors.

I currently only see two possible solutions:

1. Store the Facebook ID of the user who wants to subscribe to the feed and send out mass wall updates to every subscribed user, as soon as an author publishes a new entry.
2. Use the new subscription functionality, provided by Facebook.

To 1.:
This smells like spam.

To 2.:
Seems to be a more sane way, but I can't find any documentation for custom subscription feeds. Is this possible, at all?

Please keep in mind, that it is not sufficient to subscribe to the complete app, since every author should have an own feed.

Comment: Just to give a hint for somebody arriving at this question with answers: I ended up implementing #1.